# Data defined String to Array

Tags: java

I'm working on a game and I'm implementing objects where you can define in "TiledMap editor" what items a certain object holds. 
So I've got to an idea where I can enter the Item ID's right there like {22:4, id:amount}. When I parse the map, I retrieve that array as a string, is there a way to convert it to an array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're looking for. Do you want a way to parse your JSON string into some sort of map?

Comment: An array of what? That is the format for a single object, not an array. What is your expected "array"?

Comment: The 1st answer was the right answer, sorry for not enough information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you probably want a `Map`, not an `array` or a `List`.

```
Map<String,String> processParams(String list) {
    Map<String,String> = new HashMap<String,String>();
    int openBracket = list.indexOf("{");
    int closeBracket = list.lastIndexOf("}");
    String params = list.substring(openBracket+1,closeBracket);
    String paramList = params.split(",");

    for(String param: paramList) {
       String pData = param.trim().split(":");
       map.put(param[0].trim(),param[1].trim());
    }
    return map;
}

processParams("{22:4, id:amount}");
```

Of course, it's actually a JSON-like structure so there's probably pre-existing parsers.